# Expectation of Gaussian random measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal A, P)$ be a probability space, and let $\xi \colon \Omega \to \mathbb R^d$ be a Gaussian random variable. Moreover, let  $\mu(\xi) = \mathcal N(m(\xi), C)$ be a random Gaussian measure on $(\mathbb R^d, \mathcal B(\mathbb R^d))$, where the mean $m = m(\xi) \in \mathbb R^d$ is a linear function of the random variable $\xi$.

Let $\bar\mu$ be the probability measure on $(\mathbb R^d, \mathcal B(\mathbb R^d))$ defined by
\begin{equation}
\bar\mu = \mathbb E^{\xi}[\mu(\cdot)].
\end{equation}
Is $\bar \mu$ a Gaussian measure? In this case, is there a way to compute its parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case $\mu(\xi) = \mathcal N(\xi, C)$, and $\xi \sim \mathcal N(\xi_m,C_\xi)$, it holds
$$
\bar \mu=\mathcal N(\xi_m,C+C_\xi),
$$
which can be found by conditioning on $\xi$. Generalizing to $\mu(\xi)=\mathcal N(m(\xi),C)$ with an affine function $m$ is then trivial.